# Dynamically google map loading

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am using an application where the requirement is like that I'v a selectbox with having Different location name as  options.On selecting any location,the location will be seen on google map.I'm using IFrame to load the google map.I'm not getting any idea that how to change the "src" attribute or what will be the 'url' on selecting the location from the selectbox and also how to show it on google map using jquery.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is only "How do I change the URL of an iFrame", the following might help:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('iframe').attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

But if your question is "How do I set the location on a Google Maps map using javascript after changing a selectbox", I *strongly* recommend using the [Google Maps V3 Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) to solve your problem. Example:

HTML:

```
<select name="location">
    <option value="6,51">Location 1</option>
    <option value="5,52">Location 2</option>
</select>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var map;
$(function() {
   initialize();
   $('select[name=location]').change(function() {
      var latLng = $(this).val().split(',');
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latLng[0], latLng[1]));
   });
});

var initialize = function() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

}
</script>
```